# ¿Cómo mostrar una notificación tras finalizar una carga de datos en un submit con SweetAlert en MVC.Net?

Tags: javascript, c#, sweetalert

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto de MVC.Net, en dónde estoy haciendo la carga de un archivo por medio de un submit y por medio del otro submit hago la carga de la información de mi archivo a una base datos.

Muestro parte de mi vista en dónde tengo estos dos botones.

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <input type="submit" value="Vista Previa" class="btn btn-success" />
                    <input type="submit" onclick="mostrarAlerta()" value="Procesar Datos" class="btn btn-secondary" formaction="/File/CargarSQLServer" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Lo que busco hacer es que al momento de finalizar la carga a mi base de datos, me muestre una notificación en dónde le informe al usuario que ya se realizo la carga y tiempo después desaparecer esa alerta. Lo he intentado hacer con SweetAlert de esta forma:

```
@section Scripts {
<script>
function mostrarAlerta() {
swal({
        title: "Actualización Exitosa",
        text: "Procesamiento de datos realizado correctamente",
        icon: "success",
        button: false
    });
};
</script>
}
```

El problema que tengo es que la alerta se muestra inmediatamente que yo presiono el botón submit y desaparece en cuanto finaliza la carga de datos, que no tarda mucho tiempo. He intentado con un setTimeout para que me muestre la alerta en determinado tiempo, pero no me muestra nada de igual forma. ¿Qué tendría que hacer para que la alerta me la muestre luego de finalice la carga a mi base de datos y no al momento de presionar el botón?

De antemano agradezco la ayuda que pueda recibir.

Comment: Estas ocupando ajax?

Comment: No, solamente he estado usando JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando haces un submit tradicional el formulario va al servidor, y el servidor devuelve otra página (que puede ser la misma, pero es una nueva versión)

El funcionamiento es una especie de ping-pong de solicitudes y respuestas (Request y Response)

Lo que quiero dar a entender es que lo que haces es conceptualmente erróneo, tu al presionar el botón pasa lo siguiente:

- Se ejecuta el evento onclick mostrando la alerta
- El formulario se envía
- El contralor recibe los datos y retorna un vista
- Tu navegador recibe la vista, la cual ya NO tiene la alerta

Esto sucede tan rápido que no alcanzas a ver lo ocurrido y el `setTimeout` que querías pones evidentemente no soluciona nada.

**¿La solución?**

Es que devuelvas la página con la alerta cargada, para esto puedes ocupar un viewbag en tu controlador para determinar cuándo se debe cargar dicha alerta

En tu controlador pones:

```
ViewBag.CargarAlerta = true;
```

Y en la vista:

```
@section Scripts {
    @if (ViewBag.CargarAlerta != null && ViewBag.CargarAlerta == true){
        <script>
            swal({
                title: "Actualización Exitosa",
                text: "Procesamiento de datos realizado correctamente",
                icon: "success",
                button: false
            });
        </script>
    }
}
```